# I need to be able to extract multiple tables from website for 497 venues, as well as linked URLs

Tags: xpath, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to be able to:

1. Import multiple tables for 497 venues from the below URL to a Google sheet. URL is: [link](http://www.datascape.com.au/infocomse/morelandcc/search.cfm?Page=Details&SS=yes&DIL=no&ShowAll=Yes&LP=Details&IT=&Opt=&DirPath=114Halls%7Eand%7EMeeting%7ERooms%7Efor%7EHire&DirCond=%7BLSN:75%7D&SN=114&RequestTimeout=500&Type=Directory&Which=&String=&SubjectString=&Letter=&SubThesSN=&BFS=&Checks=&LSN=75&Group=&Surround=false&TermList=&Order=EntryName&EntrySN=62456&All=yes). The data for each venue has a hyperlink, which when selected, displays data in a details table for the venue. I would like to Details data to be transposed from vertical to horizontal.

   The first venue is !st Coburg Scouts (Coburg North), and the XPath code is `"/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[5]/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td"`. But as I am a novice with Xpath I do not know how to import all the table data for each venue in one go. As I would like to override to 50 limits using the `importxml` function.
2. The second issue I have is that I am unable to extract the URL from the hyperlink for each venue. I have tried multiple pieces of code online, but none seem to be able to extract the URL from the hyperlink. I have copied all the 497 venue hyperlinks to a Google spreadsheet from the web page.

As I am trying to provide this data to a non-profit organization, any help with these two issues would be greatly appreciated.

I tried bulkUrl code, I received an error

> "You do not have permission to call setValue (line 14).".

I authorized the use of code when I set the script up. Line 14 of script states `"sheet.getRange(2,6).setValue(url);"`. But I do not know what this means, or how to correct an error.

I also tested GetUrl script, displays an error

> "TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from null. (line 3).

Maybe it is something to do with the way the hyperlinks were constructed, as I tried several venue hyperlinks and get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://www.datascape.com.au/infocomse/morelandcc/search.cfm?Page=Details&SS=yes&DIL=no&ShowAll=Yes&LP=Details&IT=&Opt=&DirPath=114Halls~and~Meeting~Rooms~for~Hire&DirCond={LSN:75}&SN=114&RequestTimeout=500&Type=Directory&Which=&String=&SubjectString=&Letter=&SubThesSN=&BFS=&Checks=&LSN=75&Group=&Surround=false&TermList=&Order=EntryName&EntrySN=62456&All=yes", 
 "table", 65)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: (1) The importhtml function works for me for first venue, but could you provide me with a scripts, to extract all the tables for all the 497 venues, and transpose the data vertically. As the import html function has a limit of 50 requests. (2) How do you  extract urls from Hyperlinks for the 497 venues, as I cannot extract urls from Hyperlinks.

Comment: Also how do you transpose the data to columns ie headers in row 1 and data for each header in row 2. Do have to use =transpose(split(importhtml("url","Table",65))). But I do not know what delimiter to use.

Comment: Hi, I want to import all the details data from the tables for the 497 venues in one importxml request, and split the data As follows: (A) Headers in the first row, and respective data for each header in row 2. Can anyone help me with this please.